# Animation playing on entry

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have an animated table and drawer, but I am running into a dilemma just like the title says, my animation is playing on start. I don't understand why because I have the same script on the door in my scene and I have not run into the issue previously. After the initial entry, the script still works fine with opening and closing the drawer though.

Any thoughts?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
public class DoorScript: MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject OpenPanel = null;

private bool _isInsideTrigger = false;

public Animator _animator;

public string OpenText = "Press 'E' to open";

public string CloseText = "Press 'E' to close";

private bool _isOpen = false;

private void Start()
{
    OpenPanel.SetActive(false);
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        _isInsideTrigger = true;
        OpenPanel.SetActive(true);
        UpdatePanelText();
    }
}

private void UpdatePanelText()
{
    Text panelText = OpenPanel.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    if (panelText != null)
    {
        panelText.text = _isOpen ? CloseText: OpenText;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        _isInsideTrigger = false;
        OpenPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private bool IsOpenPanelActive
{
    get
    {
        return OpenPanel.activeInHierarchy;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (IsOpenPanelActive && _isInsideTrigger)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            _isOpen = !_isOpen;

            Invoke("UpdatePanelText", 1.0f);

            _animator.SetBool("open", _isOpen);
        }
    }
}
```

}
//Credit Jayanam Youtube Channel for Script

Comment: When you say "playing on start" what does that mean? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: On entry (immediately after the play button is pressed) the animation is played.

Comment: And that's not supposed to happen? When should the animation play then? Can you add screenshot of the animation tab to show how you set this up?

Comment: The script is supposed to call for the drawer to open when the player is in the trigger.

Comment: So the animation happens at the start of the game and not when the player enters trigger am I correct? or is it when player enters the trigger and animation just starts?

Comment: The animation happens at the start of the game without the player even being in the trigger. But when the player enters the trigger, the animation plays like normal, by either closing the drawer or opening the drawer.